# NLTK other language POS tagger

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am using the nltk module in python and i am trying to use this for POS tagging different languages.

There is a lot of information on how to train your own POS tagger in different languages - is there a database of really robust well built and tested NLTK POS taggers for different languages?
(It is quite easy to export POS taggers using the pickle module)

Comment: possible duplicate of [NLTK Tagging spanish words using a corpus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732465/nltk-tagging-spanish-words-using-a-corpus)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find robust and well built and tested NLTK Corpora at
http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/

You may find other corporas but these are the best

Answer (score 5):

If it is not strict to using only NLTK, you can try our robust and language-independent POS tagging toolkit [RDRPOSTagger](http://rdrpostagger.sourceforge.net/).

(License: GPLv2; Programming Language: Python & Java)

RDRPOSTagger obtains fast performance in both learning and tagging process. In addition, RDRPOSTagger achieves a very competitive accuracy in comparison to the state-of-the-art results.

Updated 18/11/2015: release version 1.2 with improved tagging accuracy, especially on morphologically rich languages.  See experimental results including performance speed and tagging accuracy in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.4021).

RDRPOSTagger supports pre-trained POS and morphological tagging models for Bulgarian, Czech, Dutch, English, French, German, Hindi, Italian, Portuguese, Spanish, Swedish, Thai and Vietnamese. RDRPOSTagger also supports the pre-trained Universal POS tagging models for 40 languages.

Comment: In case someone else need it, I did a [porting to Python 3](https://github.com/jacopofar/RDRPOSTagger-python-3)

Answer (score 2):

From what I know there is no such database of robust of well built and tested POS taggers. I do think it's a good idea though.

I tried a couple of taggers myself. For a large English corpus I've used:
http://gmb.let.rug.nl/

For Spanish I've used the one included in NLTK (cess_esp)

```
from nltk.corpus import cess_esp as cess
```

For quickly training simple taggers you can check out NLTK Trainer:

https://nltk-trainer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/train_tagger.html