# NLTK multilingual POS tagging

Tags: nltk, pos-tagger

I'm trying to pos_tag a text writen in french.

```
text = unicode("Comment faire pour que mon chien accepte le chat que je vais adopter ? ", errors='ignore')

tagged_sents = nltk.pos_tag_sents(nltk.word_tokenize(text))
```

this is giving me things that are not relevant, for example "Comment" tagged as "NNP".

The question is: how can I apply POS tagging to French (or another language besides English)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NLTK other language POS tagger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27604191/nltk-other-language-pos-tagger)

Comment: i'm looking for some code snipet i can use. i'm new to NLTK. thanks for your help.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Read the NLTK book, practice coding, and come back here when you have a specific problem in your code.