# How to do POS tagging on Telugu text?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am doing English POS tagging for so long. It's staright forward like

```
>>> text = word_tokenize("And now for something completely different")
>>> nltk.pos_tag(text)
[('And', 'CC'), ('now', 'RB'), ('for', 'IN'), ('something', 'NN'),
('completely', 'RB'), ('different', 'JJ')]
```

But I want to do it in Telugu.

I followed this article - http://jaganadhg.freeflux.net/blog/archive/2009/10/12/nltk-and-indian-language-corpus-processing-part-ii.html

And could test few inbuilt sentences. 
[image]

But I could not figure out the way to test any random Telugu text. Could some one please guide if he has experience in using NLTK for non english text.

I have total number words

```
telugu.pos
    9999
```

sentences

```
1197
telugu.pos
```

Comment: Where are you stuck at? How much annotated text do you have in Telugu? (You don't really need syntax to be annotated, if you just want to do POS tagging.)

Comment: @L3viathan: I have `1197` sentences. Like as I can directly test out English sentence `text = word_tokenize("And now for something completely different") nltk.pos_tag(text)`, how can I test Telugu sentence ? Just basic example or reference to some tutorial will be much helpful

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://nltk-trainer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/train_tagger.html). Train a tagger on your `.pos` file, then you can use it to tag.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732465/nltk-tagging-spanish-words-using-a-corpus

Comment: @alvas Thanks a lot, do you have idea, that trained tagger will be able to tag only `Telugu/Which_ever_lang_used` text only, or will it be able to tag `Lang to English` trainslitiration text also?